# Getting Chrome and Firefox version locally, C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, firefox, registry

I am just using regular C# not ASP.NET. I was wondering if I could get the version for Chrome and Firefox. I know for IE you can get the version through registry. From what I can tell Chrome and Firefox do not store that information in registry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you know the full path of an application, then you can use the [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx) class to get the version number.

Here's a simple console application that reads the installation paths of Chrome and Firefox from the registry, and outputs their version numbers:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object path;
        path = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe", "", null);
        if (path != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Chrome: " + FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path.ToString()).FileVersion);

        path = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe", "", null);
        if (path != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Firefox: " + FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path.ToString()).FileVersion);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Chrome: 24.0.1312.52
Firefox: 16.0.2
```

Comment: What OS version did you test this on?

Comment: Windows 7, 64-bit. I used the default platform target of x86 for the console app (otherwise, I probably would've had to specify the Wow6432Node registry node for Firefox, since Firefox is 32-bit).

Comment: The chrome.exe for me (Windows 7 64bit) was on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE instead of HKEY_CURRENT_USER, might as well check both locations just in case, right?

Comment: @trukin: If that's the case, then yes. Apparently Chrome offers the option of either per-user or per-machine installation.