# Using firefox to open c# url button not default browser

Tags: c#, firefox, browser

I have a very simple program that has 4 buttons each button opens a url.
What i would like is to get each button to use Firefox as the default browser.
I know i can set it as the default browser and then it will work however if a user sets internet explorer as the defualt it will open in that instead.
These url only work in Firefox as it has certificate issues.
So essentially my question is how can i change my code to make sure that if you click on any of the 4 buttons, that it will open up in firefox and not internet explorer.
Here is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://192.168.2.56/dummy.htm?settings=save&user_active1=on");
        BtnOff.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Bnton.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;   
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://192.168.2.56/dummy.htm?settings=save&user_active1=off");
        Bnton.BackColor = Color.Red;
        BtnOff.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://217.20.xxx.xxx/api/agent/pause.json?active_host=217.20.xxx.xxx&active_user=3012532&username=buildstore&password=cha9pU7U&client=snom");
        BtnDND.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
        BtnQue.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://217.20.xxx.xxx/api/agent/unpause.json?active_host=217.20.xxx.xxx&active_user=3012532&username=buildstore&password=cha9pU7U&client=snom");
        BtnQue.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
        BtnDND.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Thanks for taking the time to look appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "http://yoursite.com/dummy.htm");
```

you can keep the path of firefox.exe in config file instead of hard coding. Alternatively set the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Assuming they've installed `Firefox` in the default place, or at all. ([This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14300356/215380) can check the registry to find where FF lives.)

Comment: Not a stable solution and will not work for a web application if the question was asked for a web application(You'll be starting a process in the server not in the client's pc).

Comment: @DanKodi Untrue, this is an application. not a website

Comment: Thanks Rabi this helps allot

Comment: @EaterOfCode You mean this is a Windows Application and not a web APPLICATION.